# JavaScript Snappy Page Scrolling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to have a snappy and automated page scrolling.

I'd like to use jQuery or equivalent to get something like this:

http://www.dezinerfolio.com/wp-content/uploads/smoothscrolldemo/df_smooth_scroll.html

Additionally I'd like to have a snappy feeling to it.

When using the scrollbar or mousewheel I'd like the site so snap to a defined section.
Can this be somehow done?

Cheers,

L

Comment: It can be done yes. How far did you get with your code and where do you have problems with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is not flagged with a jQuery tag, but to accomplish such scrolling with cross-browser compatibility, I highly suggest implementing [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery scrollTo Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) ([DEMO](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)).

To be 100% honest, I am not sure how you would accomplish the scrolling with the mousewheel/scroll bar, but the plugin provides a simple interface for smooth scrolling via links/object clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like

=> http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/P5q9X/ (**jQuery**)

or => http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/TzJhu/ (**mootools**)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a really cool jQuery plugin which is exactly what you want. [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/)